# When I map a list in Clojure, how can I intersperse it with other text?

Tags: clojure

Imagine I have a list like

```
(def nodes ["a", "b", "c"])
```

I want to transform `nodes` into the following string:

```
a -> b -> c
```

**How can I do it?**

```
(apply str (mapcat
             (fn [node]
               (str node " -> ")
               )
             nodes
             )
       )
```

results in

```
"a -> b -> c -> "
```

I could now check whether or not the resulting string ends with `->` and if it does, remove the last `->`.

But this does not seem very elegant. What is the right way to do this in Clojure?

**Update 1:**

```
(transduce
  (fn [rf]
    (fn
      ([] "")
      ([result] result)
      ([result input] (str
                        result
                        "->"
                        input))
      )
    )
   cat
   ""
   nodes
  )
```

results in

```
"->a->b->c"
```

Comment: `['a' 'b' 'c']` is a vector of three symbols. Did you mean `["a" "b" "c"]` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```clj
(def nodes ["a" "b" "c"])

(clojure.string/join " -> " nodes) ;; => "a -> b -> c"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `clojure.string/join` answer is exactly right for your specific need.

However in the interests of a more general solution, `clojure.core/interpose` creates a sequence from a fixed item interposed between elements of another sequence.

```
(def nodes ["a" "b" "c"])
(interpose " -> " nodes)
;; => ("a" " -> " "b" " -> " "c")
(apply str (interpose " -> " nodes))
;; => "a -> b -> c"
```

Worth noting this takes about 3x as long so be sure you need the generality!

```
(use 'criterium.core)
(quick-bench (clojure.string/join " -> " nodes))
;; => Execution time mean : 299.877733 ns
(quick-bench (apply str (interpose " -> " nodes)))
;; => Execution time mean : 950.765805 ns
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `clojure.string/join`, you can also use `reduce` to make your own `join` if you like:

```
(second (reduce #(vector nil (str (second %1)
                                  (if (= :begin (first %1))
                                    ""
                                    " -> ")
                                  %2))
                [:begin ""]
                ["a" "b" "c"]))
```

reduce: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce

Comment: no need for this sophisticated `:begin` machinery. you can use it this way: `(reduce (fn ([] "") ([a b] (str a "->" b))) data)` . Though i find `(apply str (interpose "->" data))` a better alternative if you don't like plain old `string/join`

Comment: @leetwinski That's brilliant, I just noticed that **f should be a function of 2 arguments.** in the [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce).